# Modify external CSS values

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi I am trying to dynamicly change the height of a division using JavaScript but I can only get the JS to read the Height element of the div if it defined using style tags inside the HTML mark-up.

If its in a separate sheet it returns NaN, I'm assuming because it can't find a value and is actually returning null (I'm using ParseInt to make it work).

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="dropdown_container">
    <div id="dropdown" style="height:100px;">
    a
    </div>
</div>
```

(Wish the HTML stlye markup)

And here is the JS:

```
function clickDown() {
    var el = document.getElementById('dropdown');
    var maxHeight = 200;
    getHeight = parseInt(el.style.height.substring(0,(el.style.height.length)-2));
    console.log(getHeight);
    getHeight += 2;
    el.style.height = getHeight + 'px';
    timeoutHeightInc = setTimeout('clickDown()',15);
    if(getHeight >= maxHeight){
        clearTimeout(timeoutHeightInc);

    }
}
```

Does anyone know of a reason for this (mis?)functionaility. And a solution for it?

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N4PCf/2/).

Try moving the height over to the CSS to see the issue i'm having.

Comment: No, NaN means Not A Number, not null. Returning NaN means you're trying to read something as a number that isn't, like text.

Comment: `parseInt` automatically removes `px`, but you shouldn't omit the [radix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt). `getHeight = parseInt(el.style.height, 10)` should work if the `height` isn't `auto`. Passing a string to be evaluated by `setTimeout` is bad practice, even more when you're passing a function call. Better pass a function reference `setTimeout(clickDown, 15);` does the same without eval. Could you try reproducing the behavior on http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: @SomekidwithHTML I know it means that, I ment its probably returning null and then parseInt its trying to turn that into a number ad throwing NaN back

Comment: @wezternator yes, exactly. null is what's being returned, and `parseInt` is trying to read it as a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ParseInt is missing it's radix.

You say:

> I can only get the JS to read the Height element of the div if it
>   defined using style tags inside the HTML mark-up

Now you are only reading the div's attribute style. Which you set inline. So if you remove that, than you can not read it anymore. Make sense?

You want to get the computed height. Try: `.offsetHeight`

Basis of test-case to play with inc. fixed radix. [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c3VYc/)

UPDATE: tada: fixed, see [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c3VYc/1/)

```
function clickDown() {
    var el = document.getElementById('dropdown');
    var maxHeight = 200;
    getHeight = parseInt(el.offsetHeight,10);
    console.log(getHeight);
    getHeight += 2;
    el.style.height = getHeight + 'px';
    timeoutHeightInc = setTimeout('clickDown()',15);
    if(getHeight >= maxHeight){
        clearTimeout(timeoutHeightInc);

    }
}
```

Comment: I did not know that thanks! the problem has being bugging me for ages.